Sequence order of a cycle in R
Suppose I have graph object that forms N disconnected subgraphs, N which form a Eulerian cycle each. How do I get the sequence order of the vertices of each sub graph (noting there would be many rotations of each of the sub-graphs but I only need one sequence order per subgraph). Suppose my vertices are labelled say 1:30. Is there a function call that does this using igraph or similar? I've search the documentation but don't know how to return the sequence order of the vertices of the sub-graphs using igraph package?
I have the following code and which to return a sequence for both subgraghs (in some legitimate order).
library(igraph)

data = c(1, 19, 17, 35,    5, 13,    9, 10,   32, 39,    1, 11,
   31, 38,   18, 30,   37, 38,   3, 21,  26, 40,  24, 29,   8, 15,
   4, 23,   6, 25,   4, 12,   2,  3,  36, 40,  27, 36,   6, 20,  14,
 28,  14, 16,  7, 33)

T = matrix(data,ncol =2,byrow = TRUE)
g = graph_from_edgelist(Q, FALSE)

plot(g)


It's a bit hard to follow your question. I suppose you mean that each connected component is a cycle graph, not "Eulerian cycle".

While the answer you received looks like it was generated by an LLM, and obviously ignores the fact that you are working in R, you can in fact use eulerian_cycle() for this (non-intended) purpose after having used decomponse() to split the graph into component. You'd need to assign vertex names as strings so you can keep the correspondence between the vertices of the component graphs and the original graph.

Another alternative would be to use igraph_fundamental_cycles(), which effectively accomplishes the same in such a graph. This C functions is not yet exposed in the R interface of igraph, but you are welcome to open a feature request for it. It should be fairly easy to expose it. https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues

Ive tried: A[[1]]  = as.matrix(decompose(gr2)[[1]], matrix.type = "edgelist") but the order of the vertices isnt correct compared to the plot of plot(gr2), how would i match them to make them the same?

That's because you didn't use eulerian_cycle(), as I suggested.

This is one way to do it:
set.seed(123)
g<-sample_degseq(rep(2,20), method = 'simple.no.multiple')
V(g)$name <- as.character(V(g))
plot(g)


lapply(decompose(g), function (g) eulerian_cycle(g)$vpath)

[[1]]
+ 13/12 vertices, named, from c5ad1cc:
 [1] 1  5  20 14 10 18 4  6  8  15 7  9  1 

[[2]]
+ 6/5 vertices, named, from 6ada8b9:
[1] 2  12 3  16 13 2 

[[3]]
+ 4/3 vertices, named, from f32f4be:
[1] 11 17 19 11

